# How to unregister from ipcRenderer.on event listener?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron, ipcrenderer

In my host application I have a button, that when clicked, sends data over to my angular application with data. Like so:

```
<button (click)="onClick()">Send Some Data</button>
```

component:

```
onClick() {  
ipcRenderer.send("data-bridge",{name: 'John Smith', address: 'Main Street', date: new Date() );
}
```

In my angular application I am receiving data like so:

```
import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';

export class AppComponent {
  constructor( private electronService: ElectronService) {}

   ngOnInit() {
    if (this.electronService.ipcRenderer) {

      this.electronService.ipcRenderer.on('data-bridge', (event, data) => {
            console.log('got something', data)
        })
    }
  }
}
```

The behavior that I noticed was that for x time I click the button, I will see the alert x amount of times:

- 1 click --> 1 alert
- 2 click --> 2 alerts
- 3 click --> 3 alerts.. etc etc

So this obviously indicated to me that there is a memory leak. The solution is straightforward, remove the event listener after it receives an event.

I have tried doing something like:

```
this.electronService.ipcRenderer.on('data-bridge', (event, data) => {
        alert('got something');
        this.electronService.ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners()
}
```

But the multiple alerts still happens on a single click.

I cannot use the ipcRenderer.once method, since I need the listener to remain open, just not have multiple listeners of the same.   How can I remove the ipcRenderer.on('data-bridge', ...) event listener, so that for every click of the button, I will only have one event listener?

Comment: please share the code for `this.electronService.ipcRenderer`

Comment: added, it's just an angular wrapper for electron related api https://github.com/ThorstenHans/ngx-electron

Comment: If the none works try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68942697/22109572

Answer (score 6):

the answer from @pergy didn't work for my electron, node.js ,vue.js setup

but this did the trick:

```
this.onData = (event, data) => {
   console.log('got something', data)
})

let eventTargetRef = ipcRenderer.on('data-bridge', this.onData)

eventTargetRef.removeAllListeners('data-bridge')
```

*ipcRenderer.on()* returns a reference to the nodeEventTarget

*removeAllListeners* is a Node.js-specific extension to the EventTarget class. If type is specified, it removes all registered listeners for type, otherwise it removes all registered listeners.

[node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#class-nodeeventtarget)

Answer (score 4):

`ipcRenderer` is an [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) class, so you have `removeListener(eventName, listener)` (or `off`) method on it.

This should work

```
// on construct
this.onData = (event, data) => {
  console.log('got something', data)
})
// on init
ipcRenderer.on('data-bridge', this.onData)
// on deconstruct
ipcRenderer.removeListener('data-bridge', this.onData)
```