# Vue/Electron IPC between main and renderer

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron

I'm trying to setup communication between my Vue browser app and the electron main process, but it is not working.

Before `startBot()` is even called, I get an error message that `__Dirname` is unknown. But this constant is nowhere in to be found in the code.

What am I doing wrong?

https://gist.github.com/Quenos/7d6dbe4f5410739499ea9e3b0b4f961a.js

This is the background.js where I open the browser window with a preload. This has the purpose of making window available to the browser process

```
function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1300,
    height: 1100,
    title: "Hedgehog TRDR Bot",
    icon: path.join(__static, "hedgehog.jpg"),
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      enableRemoteModule: false,
      // __static is set by webpack and will point to the public directory
      preload: path.resolve(__static, "preload.js"),
    },
  });
```

This is said preload.js

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

const validChannels = ["READ_FILE", "WRITE_FILE"];
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("ipc", {
  send: (channel, data) => {
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
    }
  },
  on: (channel, func) => {
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      // Strip event as it includes `sender` and is a security risk
      ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
    }
  },
});
```

The main process which contains listeners that then will do file handling

```
const { ipcMain } = require("electron");
const fs = require("fs");
var file;

ipcMain.on("OPEN_FILE", (event, payload) => {
  console.log("daaro");
  file = fs.createWriteStream(payload.path);
  event.reply("OPEN_FILE", { content: "roger" });
});

ipcMain.on("TEST_FILE", (event, payload) => {
  console.log("daaro");
  file.write(payload.path);
  event.reply("OPEN_FILE", { content: "roger" });
});
```

And the browser process which send requests to do file handling:

```
async startBot() {
  window.ipc.send("OPEN_FILE", { path: "./HH_trdr_bot.csv" });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime I've found this article that perfectly answers my question

https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-safely-set-up-an-electron-app-with-vue-and-webpack-556fb491b83

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? 
I get ```TypeError: window.ipc.on is not a function``` when i use it within a .vue file

Comment: I am also getting this error, `TypeError: window.ipc.on is not a function` how did you resolve it ? @MPL, @user3067684

Answer (score 1):

Docs of Vue CLI Plugin Electron Builder contain description of how to do it, but it's a little scattered.

First, see [how to configure a preload script](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/guide.html#preload-files), i.e.:

*vue.config.js*

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      preload: 'src/preload.js',
    }
  }
}
```

and then, repeat the path in `BrowserWindow`'s `webPreferences.preload` constructor option.

```
preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
```

Finally, in `src/preload.js` expose the IPC Renderer as described in [IPC Without Node Integration](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration).

*src/preload.js*

```js
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from 'electron'

// Expose protected methods that allow the renderer process to use
// the ipcRenderer without exposing the entire object
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('ipcRenderer', {
  send: (channel, data) => {
    // whitelist channels
    let validChannels = ['toMain']
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      ipcRenderer.send(channel, data)
    }
  },
  receive: (channel, func) => {
    let validChannels = ['fromMain']
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`
      ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args))
    }
  }
})
```

It might be also a good idea to [unsubscribe the event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57423763/878514) when the component that subscribed is about to be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I made mine working by putting the `preload.js` file inside public folder, in the https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/guide.html#preload-files docs, there is a little diagram under `Folder Structure` section that says `├── public/  # Files placed here will be available through __static or process.env.BASE_URL`, so what I did is simply, use the `__static` variable as described in docs, and append it with `\preload.js`

```js
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      enableRemoteModule: false,
      preload: __static + '/preload.js', // <-- simple solution
    }
  })
```